# Write and Read an Array to a Binary File

Tags: c#, arrays, binaryfiles

I have an array consisting of 1 string value and 2 int values, which I would like to write to a binary file.

It consists of name, index and score.

I have attached the array code below, how could I write this to a file?

```
Player[] playerArr = new Player[10];
        int index = 0;
        index = index + 1;                                  // when a new player is added the index is increased by one
        Player p = new Player(txtName3.Text, index, Convert.ToInt16(txtScore.Text));    // set the values of the object p
        p.refName = txtName3.Text;                          // set refName to be the string value that is entered in txtName
        p.refTotalScore = Convert.ToInt16(txtScore.Text);
        playerArr[index] = p;                               // set the p object to be equal to a position inside the array
```

I would also like to sort each instantiation of the array to be output in descending order of score. How could this be done?

The file handling code I have so far is:

```
    private static void WriteToFile(Player[] playerArr, int size)
    {
        Stream sw;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

        try
        {
            sw = File.Open("Players.bin", FileMode.Create);
            bf.Serialize(sw, playerArr[0]);
            sw.Close();
            sw = File.Open("Players.bin", FileMode.Append);
            for (int x = 1; x < size; x++)
            {
                bf.Serialize(sw, playerArr[x]);
            }
            sw.Close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + e.Message);
        }
    }

    private int ReadFromFile(Player[] playerArr)
    {
        int size = 0;
        Stream sr;
        try
        {
            sr = File.OpenRead("Players.bin");
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            try
            {
                while (sr.Position < sr.Length)
                {
                    playerArr[size] = (Player)bf.Deserialize(sr);
                    size++;
                }
                sr.Close();
            }
            catch (SerializationException e)
            {
                sr.Close();
                return size;
            }
            return size;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("\n\n\tFile not found" + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            lstLeaderboard2.Items.Add("");
        }
        return size;
    }
```

Comment: You are looking for *serialization*

Comment: I have added what I have so far to Question

Comment: And what's wrong with the code you provide?

Comment: I dont know but I cant write the array to the file

Comment: Do you get an empty file? An exception?

Comment: you are serializing the first element in the array.not the whole array

Comment: I get an exception at                                       bf.Serialize(sw, playerArr[0]);

Comment: check the below answer, it's correct probably you didn't mark your class with `Serializable` attribute

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, you need to mark your class as Serializable, like this:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Player
```

It's fine to `Append` to a new file, so you can change your code to this:

```
    sw = File.Open(@"C:\Players.bin", FileMode.Append);
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        bf.Serialize(sw, playerArr[x]);
    }
    sw.Close();
```

(with the appropriate exception handling, and you'll obviously need to amend this if the file might already exist).

For the second part, you can sort an array like this using LINQ:

```
var sortedList = playerArr.OrderBy(p => p.Score);
```

If you require an array as output, do this:

```
var sortedArray = playerArr.OrderBy(p => p.Score).ToArray();
```

(Here, `Score` is the name of the property on the `Player` class by which you want to sort.)

If you'd like any more help, you'll need to be more specific about the problem!

Comment: Im getting an error at sw = File.Open(@"C:\Players.bin", FileMode.Append);

Comment: What is the error message? Perhaps you don't have access to the `C:` root folder? You could remove the file path and just use `File.Open("Players.bin", ...)`, which was your original location.

Comment: I dont have this error any more but i am getting a separate error on my method: WriteToFile(playerArr, i); as 'the name i doesnt exist in the current context'. This isnt allow the program to run, it is something to do with int size in the writeToFile method

Comment: I suggest you remove the 'size' parameter from the `WriteToFile` method, so you will call `WriteToFile(playerArr)`, and add the following line at the start of the `WriteToFile` method: `int size = playerArr.Count();`

Comment: I am getting an error at bf.Serialize(sw, playerArr[x]); - ArgumentNullException was unhandled

Comment: This means what it says: either `sw` or `playerArr[x]` is null. Assuming you are using the code snippet in the answer, it's probably the latter, but this really isn't enough information. I suggest you re-post your code, including the way you are setting up `playerArr` and the method call to `WriteToFile`.